# Augmented reality - move object across overlay

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5, ios6, augmented-reality

I am developing a Augmented reality application in iOS. I need to add an object, say a teapot to the screen, I should able to drag the object across the overlay of the camera and fix the object in a place. I am using the [vuforia](https://developer.vuforia.com) engine to add the object. I came across [this](https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/faq/unity-how-can-i-drag-teapot) thread to drag the 3D object to the target. But it uses C#. Is there any possibilities to achieve it in native itself? Or else some other way?

Kindly share your ideas.

Comment: Perhaps you can try manipulating models with say Ogre (C++) or Cocos3d (Objective-C). . . Ogre on iOS takes quite a lot of work to set up.

Comment: I have worked on augmented reality but could not understand your question. pleas let me know, how you want to drag an object. there are many open source libraries with diverse features, you can try them.

Comment: For example say, the camera is open and I am focusing on a table. I have some set of images. I am choosing a teacup image. The teacup comes to the screen. I should able to drag the teacup across the screen to place it some where on the table which I see through the camera.

Comment: How can I achieve dragging the image on the screen when the camera is open?

Comment: Did u find a solution to add object on camera view

Comment: @Vinupriya.. We cant achieve it through iOS SDK. I used vuforia to add a model to the iPhone screen. I am not dragging it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I can not help much with Vuforia but "Metaio" has it ready in their samples:
http://bit.ly/1I0wWzR
If you download their SDK you will have the sample code with it.